# #Project - WebView goBack() Return

Tags: java, android, webview, return

After searching on stackoverflow and testing all codes, my Return goBack(); doesn't work.

I do a WebView,
- URL work
- ZOOM work

But I need to reload last page so this is my code I added :

> MainActivity.java

```
    package org.sbynight.app;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        WebView view;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            //URL du website - DO NOT CHANGE IT 
            String url = "http://www.mydomaine.com/";

            //loads the WebView completely zoomed out
            view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            //loads WebView Client
            view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);

            //loads URL
            view.loadUrl(url);
          }


            //loads RETURN URL on lastpage
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.view.canGoBack()) {
            this.view.goBack();
            return true;
        } else {
             new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Fermer SByNight")
                .setMessage("Etes-vous sur de vouloir quittez SByNight?")
                .setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();    
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("Non", null)
            .show();
        }

        return true;
          }
    }
```

> PS: I tested with goPressed(); doesn't work too!

Comment: I tried to read your question... But it doesn't work.   Telling us that something doesn't work isn't very helpful.... Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO you want to go back to the last page if there is one to go back to when the back key is pressed?

use the following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(this.view.canGoBack()) 
    {
        this.view.goBack();
    } 
    else {
             new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Fermer SByNight")
                .setMessage("Etes-vous sur de vouloir quittez SByNight?")
                .setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                 {
                    finish();    
                 }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("Non", null)
            .show();
       }
    }
}
```

I haven't really checked the rest of your code. Just the invokable function.

Comment: Hi Gulfaran, Thanks you for your help!

I tested your code but the "return true;" error : Void methods cannot return a value - Change method Void to Boolean.

When I change, Boolean passed to RED & I have this error too : The return type is incompatible with Activity.onBackPressed().

Comment: ah yeah onkeydown requires a return onBackPressed doesnt return anything.  Unless you're using the boolean change it back to void and remove the return statements.  Sorry bout that I shouldve noticed it even without going through your code.

Comment: I do it - When I launch application & I click to button "Back", the application "CLOSED"

Comment: Closed immediately or after you click the positive button for the dialog box?

Comment: Application launch normally.  But the closed is "after I click on positive button for the dialog box".

Comment: I haven't got the webview so I cant fully test it for the previous page function but yeah when you press the back button if there isnt a page to go back to the app will bring up the dialog box and if you click yes the application will quit because of the finish() if you click no it will do nothing.

Comment: For the webview url, the good url is : "http://www.sbynight.com/a/" - & normally when you click on "back button", the dialogbox launch BUT for me the dialogbox doesnt launch & the application STOPPED & in webview url, when you enter in page, with button back you can go to the last page!!!

Comment: its because of the: "WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);"
inside oncreate. change it to just "view =(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);"